# How do I match corresponding NumPy Shape objects with (somewhat) strange parameters?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

Using the following model:

```
def unet(input_shape=(256, 256, 256)): 
  inputs = Input(input_shape)
  #print(type(inputs))

  #print(tf.shape(tf.squeeze(inputs)))

  #CurrShape = [tf.shape(inputs)[x] for x in range(5)] # 5th dimension to remove
  #print(CurrShape.shape)
  #NewInputs = tf.reshape(inputs, [CurrShape[1], CurrShape[2], CurrShape[3], CurrShape[4]])

  #Divide by 255 since that is equal to the max RGB pixel value. This ensures that every input pixel is between 0 and 1. 
  # size = Lambda(lambda x: x / 255)(inputs)

  conv1 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same')(inputs)
  #print(conv1.shape)
  conv1 = BatchNormalization()(conv1)
  conv1 = Activation('relu')(conv1)
  conv1 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same')(conv1)
  conv1 = BatchNormalization()(conv1)
  conv1 = Activation('relu')(conv1)
  pool1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2))(conv1)

  conv2 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding='same')(pool1)
  conv2 = BatchNormalization()(conv2)
  conv2 = Activation('relu')(conv2)
  conv2 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding='same')(conv2)
  conv2 = BatchNormalization()(conv2)
  conv2 = Activation('relu')(conv2)
  pool2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2))(conv2)

  conv3 = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), padding='same')(pool2)
  conv3 = BatchNormalization()(conv3)
  conv3 = Activation('relu')(conv3)
  conv3 = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), padding='same')(conv3)
  conv3 = BatchNormalization()(conv3)
  conv3 = Activation('relu')(conv3)
  pool3 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2))(conv3)

  conv4 = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), padding='same')(pool3)
  conv4 = BatchNormalization()(conv4)
  conv4 = Activation('relu')(conv4)
  conv4 = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), padding='same')(conv4)
  conv4 = BatchNormalization()(conv4)
  conv4 = Activation('relu')(conv4)
  pool4 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2))(conv4)

  max = Conv2D(1024, (3, 3), padding='same')(pool4)
  max = BatchNormalization()(max)
  max = Activation('relu')(max)
  max = Conv2D(1024, (3, 3), padding='same')(max)
  max = BatchNormalization()(max)
  max = Activation('relu')(max)

  back4 = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(max)
  back4 = concatenate([conv4, back4], axis = 3)
  back4 = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), padding='same')(back4)
  back4 = BatchNormalization()(back4)
  back4 = Activation('relu')(back4)
  back4 = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), padding='same')(back4)
  back4 = BatchNormalization()(back4)
  back4 = Activation('relu')(back4)
  back4 = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), padding='same')(back4)
  back4 = BatchNormalization()(back4)
  back4 = Activation('relu')(back4)

  back3 = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(back4)
  back3 = concatenate([conv3, back3], axis = 3)
  back3 = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), padding='same')(back3)
  back3 = BatchNormalization()(back3)
  back3 = Activation('relu')(back3)
  back3 = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), padding='same')(back3)
  back3 = BatchNormalization()(back3)
  back3 = Activation('relu')(back3)
  back3 = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), padding='same')(back3)
  back3 = BatchNormalization()(back3)
  back3 = Activation('relu')(back3)

  back2 = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(back3)
  back2 = concatenate([conv2, back2], axis = 3)
  back2 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding='same')(back2)
  back2 = BatchNormalization()(back2)
  back2 = Activation('relu')(back2)
  back2 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding='same')(back2)
  back2 = BatchNormalization()(back2)
  back2 = Activation('relu')(back2)
  back2 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding='same')(back2)
  back2 = BatchNormalization()(back2)
  back2 = Activation('relu')(back2)

  back1 = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(back2)
  back1 = concatenate([conv1, back1], axis = 3)
  back1 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same')(back1)
  back1 = BatchNormalization()(back1)
  back1 = Activation('relu')(back1)
  back1 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same')(back1)
  back1 = BatchNormalization()(back1)
  back1 = Activation('relu')(back1)
  back1 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same')(back1)
  back1 = BatchNormalization()(back1)
  back1 = Activation('relu')(back1)

  outputs = Conv2D(1, (1, 1), activation='sigmoid')(back1)
  #np_from_tensor = tf.make_ndarray(outputs)
  #print(type(outputs))
  #output_tf_array.append(outputs)

  model = Model(inputs = [inputs], outputs = [outputs])
  model.summary()

  model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999), loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

  return model
```

I want to fit it like so:

```
unet_model = unet()

print(x_train.shape) # Outputs (4, 256, 256, 256)
print(y_train.shape) # Outputs (4, 5)

unet_model.fit(x_train, y_train, steps_per_epoch=10, epochs=100)
```

But I get the following error:

```
ValueError: logits and labels must have the same shape ((1, 256, 256, 1) vs (1, 5))
```

I suspect that I may need to reshape one variable, although it doesn't seem obvious the variable I'd have to modify (but not necessarily via np.reshape()).

Could it be so that I somehow modify one or the other variable using a different technique?

Worth noting is that I have the following labels structure passed before the train_test_split() method:

```
labels = np.array([labels, labels, labels, labels, labels]) #labels have Shape(5, 5)

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(seg_images, labels, test_size=0.20, random_state=42)
```

Comment: What is the task here? Because it seems you are using a segmentation network for image classification, that is why the shapes do not match.

Comment: This does not answer what I asked.

Comment: @Dr. Snoopy Sorry, I don't understand how you mean by my task. For now, though, I need to take trained data (as x_train) and feed it to a U-Net model, then somehow fit the model with the x_train and y_train params that I have.

Comment: Tasks are like regression, image classification, image segmentation, etc. Each task uses different data, for example, why are your labels shaped as (4, 5)? What does each dimension mean?

Comment: I'd say my task is image segmentation (U-Net basically extrapolates an image to identify key regions and partition them to two distinct ones). x_train is more or less a 4D array to be fed as input to the U-Net model (so it could be input_shape=x_train[1:] rather than input_shape=(256, 256, 256)). Only the first y_train dimension should be considered, as it represents how many elements in x_train (i.e. there are four elements).

Comment: My point exactly is that your labels do not look like segmentation labels, they look like image classification labels.